# Symbol table in Prolog

Tags: prolog, symbols

I am trying to build a interpreter using Prolog and I am done with making parser but I am stuck and not getting how to make symbol table for the same. The output for my parser is like

```
Result = [[["int", "add"], "(", [["int", "a"], [",", [[...|...]|...]]], ")", "=", [["a"|...], [...|...]]], [[["int", "letin"], "(", [["int", "a"], []], ")", "=", [...|...]], [[["int", "equal"], "(", [[...|...]|...], ")"|...], [[["int"|...], "("|...], []]]]]
```

I am trying using association list for the same but not having any idea how to proceed..... just an overview will be really helpful.

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly? put 4 white-space before every line of code and see the magic.

Comment: I have not written any code it's just a output from my parser.

Comment: Then do indent it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible symbols table:

```
symtable_lookup(Sym, ST_Current, ST_Update) :-
    member(Sym, ST_Current) -> ST_Update = ST_Current ; ST_Update = [Sym|ST_Current].
```

A symbol is such a general concept, just on purpose to give a working example here is some preliminary:

```
symbol(S) :-
    atom(S), atom_codes(S, Cs), forall(member(C,Cs), code_type(C,alpha)).
```

A symbol shall be an atom containing only [specified](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=char_type/2) character codes.

To filter symbols from an arbitrary list:

```
list_symbols(L, Symbols) :-
    include(symbol, L, Symbols).
```

Finally, a test:

```
?- L=[a,+,b,-,a],list_symbols(L,S),foldl(symtable_lookup,S,[],Final).
L = [a, +, b, -, a],
S = [a, b, a],
Final = [b, a].
```

We need [foldl](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) because Prolog - similar to purely functional languages - has immutable (assign once) variables.

To adapt the example to the data you have shown, symbol/1 can be simplified:

```
symbol(S) :-
    forall(member(C, S), code_type(C, alpha)).
```